# jquery changing class on load

Tags: jquery, tailwind-css

i have problem on my project,
i want to change class on load, its look like skeleton loader
the html code look like this

```
<div class="w-full my-32">
    <div class="load animate-pulse bg-gray-800 w-1/2 mx-auto flex p-10">
        <div class="load animate-pulse berimage w-1/5 bg-center bg-cover bg-no-repeat p-16 bg-gray-300  mr-10"></div>
        <div class="flex-1">
            <p class="load animate-pulse textload bg-gray-500 text-gray-500 my-5">ddaowd;oakwd;okw<br></p>
            <p class="load animate-pulse textload bg-gray-500 text-gray-500 my-5">ddaowd;oakwd;okw<br></p>
            <p class="load animate-pulse textload bg-gray-500 text-gray-500 my-5">ddaowd;oakwd;okw<br></p>
            <p class="load animate-pulse textload bg-gray-500 text-gray-500 my-5">ddaowd;oakwd;okw<br></p>
            <p class="load animate-pulse textload bg-gray-500 text-gray-500 my-5">ddaowd;oakwd;okw<br></p>
            <p class="load animate-pulse textload bg-gray-500 text-gray-500 my-5">ddaowd;oakwd;okw<br></p>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my js

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(function() {
            if ($(`.load`).hasClass('animate-pulse')){
                $('.load').removeClass('animate-pulse').attr('bg-gray-800', 'bg-gray-500').attr('bg-gray-500', 'bg-gray-300').attr('text-gray-500', 'text-red').attr('bg-gray-300', 'bg-gray-100');
            } else {
            }
            $('.berimage').addClass('skeletonimg');

        });
    });
</script>
```

i want to change bg-gray-800 to bg-gray-500, etc

please help me :3

Comment: what do you expect to do with this code --  .attr('bg-gray-800',  'bg-gray-500')

Comment: i want to change class bg-gray-800 to bg-gray-500

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using .attr() function is wrong. Take the following code for sample, but i reckon this will help you out.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     if( flag = $('.load').hasClass('animate-pulse')){
        $.each($('.load'), function(i){
            var ele = $('.load')[i];
            $(ele).removeClass('animate-pulse').addClass("random");
         }
       );
     
     }else{
        console.log("else")
     
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i used toggleClass but not every class changing

```
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(function() {
            if ($(`.load`).hasClass('animate-pulse')){
                $('.load').toggleClass('bg-gray-800', 'bg-gray-500').toggleClass('bg-gray-300', 'bg-gray-100').removeClass('animate-pulse');
            } else {
            }

            if ($(`.textload`).hasClass('bg-gray-500')) {
                $('.textload').toggleClass('bg-gray-500', 'bg-red-400').toggleClass('text-gray-500', 'text-red-100');
            }
            else{}

            $('.berimage').addClass('skeletonimg');
        });
    });
```